# What are the rules for blanket implementations regarding modules?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, trait-objects

I've been trying to find documentation on how Rust resolves trait blanket implementations in case module boundaries are involved, but didn't find much directly related to it.

Let's consider an example with two similar, but slightly different code snippets: 
The first one is code that does compile just fine, but suffers an infinite runtime recursion. This happens because the blanket implementation of the `ClonableIterator` for  `T: Iterator+Clone` matches against the `Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>>` which is, thanks to our manual implementation of `Clone` and `Box`'s blanket implementation of `Iterator` now `Iterator+Clone`.

```
//the trait itself, with the indirection to call box_clone on the base type
trait ClonableIterator<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a u32> + 'a {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>>;
}

//The blanket implementation of the trait for all clonable iterators
impl<'a, T: Iterator<Item = &'a u32> + Clone + 'a> ClonableIterator<'a> for T {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

//Clone for the box. Does not work
impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
      (*self).box_clone()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let iter1 : Box<dyn ClonableIterator> = Box::new(input.iter());
    let iter2 : Box<dyn ClonableIterator> = Box::new(iter1.clone().filter(|&&x| x%2 == 0));
    println!("{} {}", iter1.sum::<u32>(), iter2.sum::<u32>())
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ffe6f2f928640f680119a21c7858baf))

The second snippet is just a slight modification of the above, namely the implementation of the `Clone` trait has been moved to a submodule. However, it is working and doing what one expects. Trait objects created of `ClonableIterator` are both, `Clone` and `Iterator`, and calling the `clone()` method on them creates an actual copy of the boxed iterator. 
Both, `Iterator` methods and `clone()` can be directly called on the `Box<dyn ClonableIterator>`, and iterators created from it are again `Clone+Iterator`, so a `ClonableIterator` trait object can be created from them.

```
//the trait itself, with the indirection to call box_clone on the base type
trait ClonableIterator<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a u32> + 'a {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>>;
}

//The blanket implementation of the trait for all clonable iterators
impl<'a, T: Iterator<Item = &'a u32> + Clone + 'a> ClonableIterator<'a> for T {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<'a>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

//a helper module, to prevent the above blanket implementation from matching
//the Box<dyn super::ClonableIterator<'a>>.
//I can't find the documentation how this works, but it does work.
mod helper {
    impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn super::ClonableIterator<'a>> {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
          (*self).box_clone()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let iter1 : Box<dyn ClonableIterator> = Box::new(input.iter());
    let iter2 : Box<dyn ClonableIterator> = Box::new(iter1.clone().filter(|&&x| x%2 == 0));
    println!("{} {}", iter1.sum::<u32>(), iter2.sum::<u32>())
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1fcec23e0be3f75a724548f9dac8df33))

Could someone please explain or maybe link relevant documentation on how the rules for applying a trait blanket implementation differ from the rules for having the trait itself available?

Comment: Smells like a bug in trait coherence to me.  But in any event, surely you want `(**self).box_clone()` instead of `(*self).box_clone()`?  Which will prevent the infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit tired yesterday (it was 11 pm or so), and first missed the obvious solution. That's why I even tried putting the Clone implementation in its own module (after finding similar code _somewhere_ online). Looking at it after a good night of sleep it's obvious that the first `*` just makes `self` out of `&self`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete citation of the reference manual for all the parts here, but the difference I see between these two cases is `ClonableIterator` is not *visible in* `mod helper` (there is no `use super::ClonableIterator`). Thus, the trait is not consulted *for arbitrary types* when looking up methods, but (evidently) it is for `dyn super::ClonableIterator`, presumably because it would be gratuitously unhelpful to not do that.

So the [method lookup procedure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) will be doing approximately this:

1. We start with `*self`, an explicit dereference of `&Box<dyn CloneableIterator<'a>>` of type `Box<dyn CloneableIterator<'a>>`.

   - Does this have an inherent method named `box_clone()`? No.
   - Does any visible trait have a method named `box_clone()`?

     - In the first program, yes (`ClonableIterator` was declared in the same scope), so that one is called.
     - In the second program, no, so continue.
2. Dereference `Box<dyn CloneableIterator<'a>>` to obtain `dyn CloneableIterator<'a>`.

   - Does this have an inherent method named `box_clone()`? No.
   - Does any visible trait have a method named `box_clone()`? Yes, apparently `CloneableIterator` is visible for the `dyn` type unconditionally.